# What am I supposed to do instead of using a global variable?

Tags: python

I am making a simple text-based rpg in python. As it currently sits, all of the data is in it's own module, like the player object and items. I am reading in some places that I am not supposed to use global variables, but I don't understand how I am going to put the player and item data in functions without them being global? Am I supposed to use non local variables or something? I hope I am being concise enough here. I will try to provide some example code for context.

```
PlayerName = "Default"

def choose_name():
    PlayerName = input("What is your player's name?")

def game_loop():
    choose_name()

game_loop()
```

I am aware that I did not put global inside of the choose_name() function. I am still new to python, so please be patient with me as I am learning.

Comment: Have you learned about function parameters?

Comment: Or alternatively, classes?

Comment: Does including a global variable as a parameter in a function change the scope of it? @cricket_007

Comment: It "shadows" the global name by making a variable of the same name in local scope

Comment: @kaya3 If a variable is a member of a class, does that change how scope works?

Comment: Classes are a way of sharing and maintaining data between multiple functions, without having to pass that data between the functions explicitly.

Answer (score 2):

For the concept of "configuration" variables or constants, those are definitely allowed to be global.

The suggestion should be rephrased as "limit the scope of the variables" and don't use `global` keyword excessively

Regarding the example, make the function return something back to the local scope of the game loop

```
def choose_name():
    return input("What is your player's name?")

def game_loop():
    name = choose_name()
    print('Hello, {}!'.format(name)) 

game_loop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Game, Player and Item clearly seem like object-oriented classes, so you should use classes to store variables, instead of using global ones (that is if you don't want to pass them as function arguments).

```py
class Game:
    # use static variable
    player = None
    # or define it for game class:
    def __init__(self):
        self.player = None

    def game_loop():
        self.player = Player()    

class Player:
     def __init__(self):
        self.name = input("What is your player's name?")


game = Game()
game.game_loop()
```

You can read more on OOP in Python 3 at [this link](https://realpython.com/python3-object-oriented-programming/).

Comment: The context is not clearly defined in the question - one way to have only one instance of game is to use a Singleton Class: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python_design_patterns/python_design_patterns_singleton.htm

Comment: I dont have access to adding comments to questions as of now - I can only add answers. But yes, I did think of asking before. I only decided based on existing comments.

Answer (score 0):

as you already recognized, global variables are a bad idea in most cases. So what about using a class? I give you an example:

```
class Game(object):
    def __init__(self, player_name="Default"):
        self.player_name = player_name

    def choose_name(self):
        self.player_name = input("What is your player's name?")

    def game_loop(self):
        self.choose_name()


Game().game_loop()
```

I hope I could help. Don't be afraid to ask further questions.

Best regards,
kruemelbacke